# Reading sub-object vector with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, vector, rapidjson, stdany

This is my json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "text": "hey stackoverflow",
        "array_1": [
            ["hello", "world", 11, 14]
        ]
    },
}
```

I have managed to extract the `text` attribute like so:

Code:

```
document.Parse(request_body);

auto& data = document["data"];

std::string text = data["text"].GetString();
printf("text: %s\n", text.c_str());
```

Output:

```
text: hey stackoverflow
```

Now i need to extract `array_1` as a `std::vector<std::vector<std::any>>`.

I guess that, to have such a data type, i will have to iterate through `data["array_1"]` using rapidjson's types to fill vectors.

The problem is that even after trying to replicate what i saw on the internet, i'm still unable to read the values inside `data["array_1"]`.

Code:

```
auto& array_1 = data["array_1"];
static const char* kTypeNames[] = { "Null", "False", "True", "Object", "Array", "String", "Number" };

for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr = array_1.Begin(); itr != array_1.End(); ++itr){
    printf("item\n");
    for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator itr2 = itr->Begin(); itr2 != itr->End(); ++itr2){
        printf("Type is %s\n", kTypeNames[itr->GetType()]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
item
Type is Array
Type is Array
Type is Array
Type is Array
```

But i need to have:

```
item
Type is String
Type is String
Type is Number
Type is Number
```

### EDIT

I was calling the `GetType` on the wrong iterator..

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    printf("Type is %s\n", kTypeNames[itr2->GetType()]);
```

not

```
    printf("Type is %s\n", kTypeNames[itr->GetType()]);
```

you are printing out the type of the `item`, aka `["hello", "world", 11, 14]`, not the elements of `["hello", "world", 11, 14]` repeatedly.

Alternatively:

```
for (auto&& item : array_1.GetArray()) {
  printf("item\n");
  for (auto&& elem : item.GetArray()){
    printf("Type is %s\n", kTypeNames[elem.GetType()]);
  }
}
```

to get rid of some iteration noise.  (Requires [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and rapidJson v1.1.0)

Comment: Thank you very much, i wasn't paying attention on the basics so i did not saw that..so sry.. Thank you for the tip btw !

Comment: i have c++17 and latest rapidjson version but i get a "no viable 'begin' function available" on the "for (auto&& item : array_1)". Thanks for your help anyway ! :D

Comment: @lifeguru42 Huh, I was quoting some docs.  Aha: https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html I missed something -- need `.GetArray()`, probably because a json item could either be an array or an object, and iterating works differently on the two.